# How can I take snap shot and convert to PDF of section of HTML page in JavaScript without any Library?

Tags: javascript, html, css, screenshot

I do not know but This question might have straight forward answer that "Not Possible" ? But I think definately there should be a way to do this, May be using some OS level work. My Question can be better understand  by watching this code.

```
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
  <div> .......... </div>
  <div> .......... </div>
  <div> .......... </div>
  <div> .......... </div>
  <div id="my-required-section"> .......... </div>
  <div> .......... </div>
  <div> .......... </div>
  <div> .......... </div>
  <div> .......... </div>
  <div> .......... </div>
</body>
```

> This complete html is the rendered DOM after all server side and client side code has been executed. Now I have Browser view of this complete page DOM, I just want to get SnapShot of a specific part for example the Browser view of a particular div with id = `my-required-section`.

In Other Word -

> Lets suppose take complete snapshot of this DOM from `<html>` to `</html>` than crop only a part (represented by that DIV with id `my-required-section`)

I will be thank full Even if you suggest me a good article related to this kind of problem.

I will add more context to the problem for better understanding the problem.

1. I have complete HTML code inside a that particular DIV. But How can I get the CSS property of it parent elements, because What I want is exact designed snapshot of that div when we see that by Inspect element through chrome developer tool

Comment: `element.innerHTML`? What do you mean by "snapshot"? Like an actual image? Or its current state?

Comment: What information would you like in the `SnapShot`? Knowing that would help us answer =)

Comment: @takendarkk I have added a line. I hope you can understand the problem

Comment: @Hodrobond ^ The complete Information inside that DIV and same design as we see in browser

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using HTML5/Canvas/JavaScript to take screenshots](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4912092/using-html5-canvas-javascript-to-take-screenshots)

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan Actually requirement is different, So I edited the question title. I need Snapshot at some place and PDF at some place.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to retrieve information contained within the [Document Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document)?

If so, I would advise looking into [css selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors), as they may be used to retrieve particular elements of a web page. In your example, you may retrieve the selected element using `document.getElementById("my-required-section");`

[jsfiddle (be sure to have console open)](https://jsfiddle.net/gtdq61h0/)